# Selenium Webdriver storing and asserting text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, methods, webdriver

I'm currently attempting to store the text value of a field within one method, to then use in a separate method to assert against.

Here is the method I'm using which is storing the text (This is working and printing to the console correctly)...

```
    protected void selectLeadPassenger(String name) throws Throwable {
    moveToElement("lead-dropdown-complete", name);
    waitForElementToBeVisible("#lead-dropdown-complete > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > h3");
    String leadPassengerName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(@text(), " + name + ")]")).getText(); //THIS IS THE FIELD I AM STORING
    System.out.print(leadPassengerName); //THIS IS PRINTING OUT THE CORRECT VALUE WITHIN THE CONSOLE
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(@text(), " + name + ")]")).click();
    System.out.println(name + " searched for and selected within the 'LEAD PASSENGER' field");
}
```

However, I'm struggling to find a way to then use 'leadPassengerName' within a separate method to assert against, for example I've tried the following...

```
protected void validateLeadPassengerName() throws Throwable {
    String checkText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(@data-bind, 'vm.LeadPassengerName')]")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue("", checkText.contains(leadPassengerName));
}
```

I'm certain the issue is with the way I'm storing 'leadPassengerName' because within the validateLeadPassengerName method it appears in red with the following error message "cannot resolve symbole 'leadPassengerName'".

Comment: Since [*the goal of writing a blog post is to provide useful information to others with a minimum of noise and clutter*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/why-is-saying-thank-you-in-question-undesirable), please remove your signature/thanks/will-be-appreciated. That being said, welcome on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve the issue. First of all it has nothing to do with selenium, it is more about data flow in a programming language

```
protected string validateLeadPassengerName(string leadPassengerName) throws Throwable {
    String checkText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(@data-bind, 'vm.LeadPassengerName')]")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue("", checkText.contains(leadPassengerName));
    return checkText;
}
```

So when you can call your function

```
 String leadPassengerName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(@text(), " + name + ")]")).getText();
validateLeadPassengerName(leadPassengerName)
```

Also like you have driver shared across the functions by creating a variable at class level, you can do the same thing for storing the lead passenger name

Comment: Thanks for this, the only thing I'd add is that I had to put String leadPassengerName as a global class, then within my method I called leadPassengerName = ...

Comment: Yes, different ways to solve it. You should learn which ones are recommended practice and which ones are not.